# Configure httpd to same settings as stock CentOS/RHEL 7?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I'm trying to upgrade httpd `2.4.6` to `2.4.25` with http/2 enabled on my CentOS 7.2. Since `2.4.6` is the latest version available on the yum repository, I understood that I must compile it myself.

By default, the freshly-complied httpd is being installed to a different path than the default package shipped with the yum repository.

How can I configure, compile and install it with exactly the same settings like the stock CentOS official version, effectively upgrading the current version?

My `apachectl -V` output is:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jul 18 2016 15:30:14
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: Have you consider to get the source package for apache, change the archive and SPEC file and recompile it?

Comment: when you say "*install* it with exactly the same settings", did you really mean "configure, compile, and install ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" way to do it is build or adapt an rpm package. On top of making sure that you get the same configuration, you avoid breaking future updates.

I usually start my rpm work based on the closest version I can find for the target platform. In your case I have found an rpm of the same exact version:

https://codeit.guru/en_US/2017/01/apache-httpd-2-4-25-built-against-openssl-1-0-2j-with-http2-for-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-centos/

With minimal edits you should be able to adapt the SRPM provided by codeit to suit your needs